# Knockout JS: Validation of Textboxes inside the table for-each

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have html table whose columns are dynamically generated, where each column is a textbox. I am struggling to work out is how to validate these textboxes.

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/4djn2zee/

So on the save button click I want to validate user input.

The requirement is:

- I want to make all but one column required field.
- I want to apply regex to certain columns (based on column name) as some columns are chars only whereas some only numbers.

Here is my construct of the texbox:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: valuesData, as: 'rowData'}">
<tr data-bind="foreach: { data: $parent.columns, as: 'column' }">
  <!-- NEW: bind to the corresponding property/observable in ValuesData -->
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-bind="textInput: rowData[column.Property]" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="button" value="Remove Row" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow" class="btn btn-danger" />
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Its a little complex requirement and have been struggling to gets head up on this.

Any pointers to this ?

Anyone/??

Comment: Your column-model has a `Caption`-property, why not add a property next to it to store the regex?

Comment: @Stanislas Would appreciate if you could provide me an example how could I set this up.